# How to determine what the repair people did to fix my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair

Recently, my MacBook stopped powering up. When pressing the power button, nothing at all happened. The usual green-yellow light on the power supply appeared normal, but no lights or sounds came from the MacBook itself. Only very rarely, after trying many times throughout the week, would it power on after pressing "power on". Once on, it never powered it off without me instructing it to shutdown.

I took the MacBook to a repair store. They said I should leave it for a few days. When I returned, it worked, albeit they lost a few of the screws, didn't completely bolt the parts firmly together, and got it really dirty. They refused to give me any details about what they did to fix it, but showed me that it works fine now. I don't know if they made significant changes, such as replaced internal parts, or just wiggled some wire and got it working again.

Are there any steps I can take to investigate the computer to identify how the repair store fixed?

Comment: It seems strange that they would not tell you if they replaced something in the machine. They must have opened it up for some reason though, since the screws are missing — so maybe take a peek yourself and see if anything is different. One thing I thought of, is that if you've done a system report at some point before taking your system in and had saved it then you could compare everything in detail.

Comment: I assume they charge you for the fix. Therefor they must tell you what they did. Most place will charge you for just looking. And extra for work done and parts. I suspect that they took it apart had a wiggle and put it back together and it suddenly started working without them know what part was loose. But as I say the bill should be itemised..

Comment: Did you pay them?

Comment: Yes, I paid them. I tried to understand what they did before paying them.

Answer (score 1):

I work at an Apple Authorized Service Provider, and the fact that they won't tell you what they did means it was probably just an SMC reset that took two seconds. From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295):

> The System Management Controller (SMC) is responsible for many
>   low-level functions on Intel-based Macs. These functions include:
>
> - Responding to presses of the power button

I'm guessing they didn't tell you this because all it takes to reset the SMC is holding down 3 keys and the power button at the same time while plugged in, and you'd possibly argue about having to pay them. It seems pretty shady of them, because we have machines come in needing a simple SMC reset all the time, and most of the time we waive labor charges, but for them to not even tell you that that's what they did doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that as the poster above says, it was an SMC reset which is documented on the Apple Support site : [1] https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295

[1]: Intel-based Macs: Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC)